# SQLite query not work on Android rawQuery

Tags: android, database, sqlite, select-query

**Edit:** *Problem solved, query is correct. My problem is; 
I work with local database. And i'm not reach database directly from assets folder. My code copy database from assets folder to SD card when database not exits on SD card. Therefore my database changes only effect database in asset folder. And i was tried right query on old database.
Sorry for the question.*

I tried my SQLite query on *DB Browser for SQLite* and **it's worked.**

But on Android same query not worked.

```
 String[] a = new String[1];
 a[0] =   yazilanKelime + '%';
 Cursor friendCursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM kelimeler WHERE kelime LIKE ? ORDER BY sayi DESC LIMIT 10", a);
```

If i remove "ORDER BY sayi DESC" part, it's work. Where am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Return this Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sayi (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM kelimeler WHERE kelime LIKE ? ORDER BY sayi DESC LIMIT 10

DB Schema:
[image]

Comment: Trying null instead of a?

Comment: `String[] a = new String[yazilanKelime + "%"];`

Comment: try with `a[0] =   yazilanKelime + "%";`

Comment: a[0] = "%" + yazilanKelime + "%";

Comment: Please explain what "not worked" means to you.

Comment: Return this Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sayi (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM kelimeler WHERE kelime LIKE ? ORDER BY sayi DESC LIMIT 10

I think my problem is "order by" part of query.

Comment: The problem is in your table creation. But I can't tell you which part exactly, since you didn't show your code.

Comment: Change with `yazilanKelime + "%";` but still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception says, `no such column: sayi` means that the column `sayi` does not exists in your table `kelimeler`. Check this first.